# Cannot Extend Laravel Model

Tags: laravel-5

I have 2 models. The User model, and the relationship works correctly, I use tinker, and I can see the application that is associated with the user.

```
User::find(4)->application
```

However, the application will not return the user - in tinker I get null, whats worse, if I try to access rep in tinker, I get Bad Method Exception Call

```
Application::find(8)->user
```

is null

Note: I have an id column in users which I "find" users. and there is "ucid" column in users that I have defined as the primaryKey in Application.

Application Model:

```
class Application extends Model
{
    protected $data = [
        'data' => 'array'
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'ucid';
    protected $fillable = [
        'ucid', 'data'
    ];
    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'ucid');
    }
    public function rep() 
    {
        return 'Test';
    }
}
```

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function application()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Application::class,'ucid');
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this? Let me know if it works..

Application Model

```
class Application extends Model
{
    protected $data = [
        'data' => 'array'
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'ucid';
    protected $fillable = [
        'ucid', 'data'
    ];
    public function user() 
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'ucid');
    }
    public function rep() 
    {
        return 'Test';
    }
}
```

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function application()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Application::class, 'ucid', 'ucid');
    }
}
```

As you see I switched `hasOne` and `belongsTo` in your models.

Also.. third argument on `hasOne` of `Application Model` is not required since value from $primaryKey will be used since its defined, however you have to specify the third argument in `belongsTo` of `User` model

Comment: That works, but why? also I may have 2 users with the same application, how does that work?

Comment: @JamesBailey User model doesn't have a knowledge of you defined customer $primaryKey when executing its sql query.

Comment: @JamesBailey you'll have to convert your relationship into many-to-many with pivot table